# How to SELECT lines where COUNT DISTINCT is MAX?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, max

this may be an easy question but basically I would like to get to SELECT only the lines of highest number of occurence for an experiment in SQL SERVER.
I have a query that produces the following data:

```
SELECT [JOB ROLE], [CITY], COUNT(DISTINCT([EMPLOYEE_ID])) as [COUNT]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [JOB ROLE], [CITY]
```

[image: Result of existing query]

I would like to reach to the following outcome to SELECT only the lines where the COUNT DISTINCT of EMPLOYEE_ID is MAX:

[image: Desired outcome]

Many thanks in advance for the kind help and suggestions on how to get here the easiest!

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function,  it's a _set quantifier_. Skip those extra brackets and simply write `COUNT(DISTINCT [EMPLOYEE_ID])` to make code clearer.

Comment: What should happen is multiple groups share the maximum? Is there a rule for tie breaking, or are all groups returned, or, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about ties, you can do it with FIRST_VALUE() window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [JOB ROLE], 
       FIRST_VALUE([CITY]) OVER (PARTITION BY [JOB ROLE] ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT([EMPLOYEE_ID])) DESC)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [JOB ROLE], [CITY]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TOP WITH TIES` and `RANK()`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES [JOB ROLE], [CITY], COUNT(DISTINCT [EMPLOYEE_ID]) as [COUNT]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [JOB ROLE], [CITY]
ORDER BY RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT [EMPLOYEE_ID]) DESC;
```

Or, use a subquery and `RANK()`:

```
SELECT [JOB ROLE], [CITY], [COUNT]
FROM (SELECT [JOB ROLE], [CITY],
             COUNT(DISTINCT [EMPLOYEE_ID]) as [COUNT],
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT [EMPLOYEE_ID]) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM MyTable
      GROUP BY [JOB ROLE], [CITY]
     ) jc
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

The question seems to have changed to be the most common job role *per city*.  The above queries are easily modified:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES [JOB ROLE], [CITY], COUNT(DISTINCT [EMPLOYEE_ID]) as [COUNT]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY [JOB ROLE], [CITY]
ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [JOB ROLE] ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT [EMPLOYEE_ID]) DESC;
```

Or, use a subquery and `RANK()`:

```
SELECT [JOB ROLE], [CITY], [COUNT]
FROM (SELECT [JOB ROLE], [CITY],
             COUNT(DISTINCT [EMPLOYEE_ID]) as [COUNT],
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [JOB ROLE], ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT [EMPLOYEE_ID]) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM MyTable
      GROUP BY [JOB ROLE], [CITY]
     ) jc
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! This unfortunately only return to me one line, selecting the most common [JOB ROLE] and [CITY], instead of all [JOB ROLE] values with the most common [CITY].

Comment: @gonzika Is that not what you asked for ? When looking at the desired output I think this was your question, so this answer is valid in my opinion

Comment: @GordonLinoff the question is the same as it was when first posted: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64971175/revisions